# Azure ML Designer - Unable to connect dataset (any directory type) to clean missing data module (dataframedirectory type) in designer

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Unable to connect dataset (any directory type) to clean missing data module (dataframedirectory type) in designer. Please advise. Screenshot of trying to connect is below where the clean missing module connection point is not highlighted to connect both modules, which i am assuming is because of type mismatch. Dataset output is of type "AnyDirectory" type where as clean missing module type is "dataframedirectory". How to cast in designer?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs3uV.png

Answer (score 0):

The fix is not in Designer but in your **Datasets**.

When creating a dataset in AML from **web files**, select `Tabular` as the *Dataset type* property. Then the dataset will be a Tabular dataset, which can be connected with DataFrameDirectory.

[image]